# making it so right clicking in WSL / Ubuntu 20.04 / vim pastes code?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, vim, ubuntu-20.04, wsl2

I'm running Windows 10 / WSL2 / Ubuntu 20.04 and when I right click in vim the text at the bottom left goes from `-- INSERT --` to `-- (insert) VISUAL --`. I'd like it to paste whatever was in the copy buffer, instead, similar to what PuTTY does.

Any ideas as to how I might achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Mine works the way you want. If you click the title bar of Ubuntu, choose Properties, is QuickEdit Mode checked?

Answer (score 1):

You can **copy**/**paste** in `INSERT` mode by holding down the `shift` key.

---

**Not recommended!** This will disable the ability to scroll with the mouse.

Alternatively you can disable mouse support to paste without holding `shift`. To do this, add the following to `.vimrc`:

```
set mouse=
```

---

For understanding `:h mouse` or read [here](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27mouse%27).

Excerpt from VIM help:

> When enabling the mouse in a terminal, copy/paste will use the `"*` register if there is access to an X-server. **The xterm handling of the mouse buttons can still be used by keeping the shift key pressed.**